# Site rooms button hover color hides the logo

Tags: bug, design

When I hover the site rooms buttons, the hover color is the same as the logo color which make it invisible. Maybe we should find an alternative color for it ?

[image]

Comment: This is just an idea, but perhaps the "white" version of the logo should be used? It's not very visible even on the blue background using the dark version.

Comment: Related: [Can we enhance the favicon on a dark background?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6200)